Capacitance between conducting plane and a circle on this plane
Imagine I have a very thin conducting plane. On this plane, I carve out some of the conducting material, on a circle with radius $R$ and width $r$.
I am wondering if there is an analytical formula for the capacitance between the conducting plane and this little island, or at least get an idea on how it scales with $R$ and $r$. I first thought about solving this like for the capacitance of concentric spheres, but it turns out to be harder than I thought.


a good bet for you maybe IEEE or IEE and look for suspended slot antennas or resonators

since you are asking for a static capacitance and not some transient situation you may be able to take advantage of axial symmetry. Ignoring the angle coordinate you get the Laplace equation as $\nabla^2 \phi =\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r})+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=0$. This is separable as $\phi(r,z)=A(r)B(z)$ and $\frac{1}{Ar} \frac{d}{dr}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{dA}{dr})=-\frac{1}{B}\frac{d^2B}{dz^2}=\pm m^2$, the value of $m$ is to be determined by matching the boundary conditions, say $\phi(0<r<a, 0)=1$ and $\phi(b<r, 0)=0$.

The equation for $B$ is solved by exponentials/harmonics and the one for $A$ are Bessel functions; it will be a lot of fun...
